Docker + Laravel + Redis: caching and pushing jobs not working
We do have an application running on a Server with a setup of Docker + Laravel + Redis + other services.
**
QUEUE_CONNECTION + CACHE_DRIVER are set to redis**
ISSUE:
Laravel application can not set/get Cache items and cannot push to the Queue
Everything was running fine until two days ago.
Somehow the network was missing and after I recreated it, caching + pushing jobs from the laravel container to the queue was not working anymore.
Here a bit about the setup:

crew_app => runs our custom laravel image
supervisor => runs workers of Horizon
scheduler
redis

Operations that do or do not work:

WORKS scheduler can push jobs to the queue
WORKS queue processes jobs
WORKS crew_app is connected to redis (tested by pinging from crew_app to redis and vice versa)
!!!! crew_app cannot flush single Cache tags (tested with tinker: created Cache item with tag, value is returned at get, flushed with Cache::tags(['tag']=->flush(), item still cached - nothing flushed)
!!!! crew_app cannot push jobs

What I did so far:

checked logs => no errors
restarted & recreated containers
pulled latest redis image
completely removed redis container + volume and recreated
checked configs + setup
checked network + volumes
tinker: could not get a set cache item again
pushing jobs from crew_app => not received in horizon

I really want to avoid having to setup the whole system newly.
I can paste docker-compose and other configs if needed. But I am pretty sure that there is no issue there as everything was already working seemlessly.
Hope someone of you guys can help me!
